# Why is there a left ventricular volume overload in patients with Ventricular septal defect?

Tags: cardiology, practice-of-medicine, heart, shunt, ventricular-spetal-defect

With VSD left to right shunt in systole logically should dilate right ventricle due to volume overload since left side pressure is higher then the right.

Answer (score -1):

This happens because with the left to right shunt blood is shunted directly into RVOT and and into pulmonary artery and thus right ventricle is spared but left atria and ventricle become enlarged because of increase flow through the lungs.